# How to programmatically determine whether a spatial reference factory code is valid?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, arcpy, coordinate-system

I am using the following code segment to create a spatial reference.

```
    spatialReferance = arcpy.SpatialReference()
    spatialReferance.factoryCode = spatialReferanceFactoryCode
    spatialReferance.create()
```

But it gives the following error:

> Runtime error : ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
>   the input string is not a geographic or projected coordinate system

How can I programmatically determine whether a factory code is valid or not?

Comment: What is the value of `spatialReferanceFactoryCode`?

Comment: @om_henners: spatialReferanceFactoryCode = 32146

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [Do ArcGIS SpatialReference object factory codes correspond with EPSG numbers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18651/do-arcgis-spatialreference-object-factory-codes-correspond-with-epsg-numbers) in particular @mkennedy and @blah238 answers.

As to whether a factory code is valid or not... In Python, you can use the [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) method (Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission)

```
try:
    spatialReference.factoryCode = spatialReferenceFactoryCode
    spatialReference.create()
except RuntimeError:
    print 'factoryCode is not valid'
```

Comment: Actually I want to check if the code valid or not. Is there any property that can tell me that?

Comment: @Emi Try [spatialreference.org](http://spatialreference.org) ([it is](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/32146/) by the way)

Comment: @om_henners: sorry for the misunderstanding. Actually I want to do it programmatically.

Comment: There is no way to check whether a code is valid without trying to create a coordinate system (spatial reference).

Comment: +1 for EAFP method. That is *so* python! Try to do it and catch it if it breaks.. there isn't a IsNumeric for strings in python (off topic but related) possibly because you can find out in the same way.