# How can I convert esriMeters to Lat/Lng?

Tags: javascript, json

I am pulling a JSON list of features into a web page. The points come as esriMeters and the rest of my app uses Lat/Lng. How can I do this conversion in the browser (javascript)?

Comment: Are you using the ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Comment: I haven't used that but would if that's the most efficient way. It looked to be a limited set of six specific functions.

Comment: Where are you seeing that? This is the API I'm talking about: http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/

Comment: I see the API reference now. On this page, it just said "download all six javascript functions" http://www.esri.com/getting-started/developers/get-started/javascript

Comment: So if I use their JS library, do you know the function that will do the conversion?

Comment: If you aren't already building your app on top of it, I don't know whether it can or should be shoehorned in just to do the coordinate conversion. You might try [proj4js](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj4js/) instead.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need! If I am getting wkid=26915 features from ArcGIS, is that the same as EPSG:26915 referenced in the proj4js?

Comment: Yes they should be the same: [Do ArcGIS SpatialReference object factory codes correspond with EPSG numbers?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/18676/753)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're executing a [query against an ArcGIS service](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/rest/apiref/query.html), just set the output spatial reference to the geographic coordinate system of your choice (e.g. 4326 for WGS84). This will give you lat / long.

Comment: Ha - I swear I had tried requesting several combinations of formats last night but this time it's working. Getting data as needed from arcgis now.

Comment: +1, that's certainly more straightforward :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the [proj4js](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj4js/) library (JavaScript port of the [PROJ.4](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/) C library).