# WKID matching EPSG

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates

Is there a way to matching the code of ESRI WKID with EPSG code? I'm trying to find the coordinate system of PCS Name = CGRS_1993_LTM. Which has WKID:102319 code. But I donn't know the EPSG code.

Comment: Does this answer help? http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/18675/43

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Up to now, the EPSG database has no CRS for Cyprus. There is an open ticket for it since November 2014 `EPSG::2014.091`.

The code you mention is from ESRI, and according to http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcims/10.0/mainhelp/mergedProjects/ArcXMLGuide/elements/pcs.htm#102319 the values are:

```
PROJCS["CGRS_1993_LTM",
GEOGCS["GCS_CGRS_1993",
DATUM["D_Cyprus_Geodetic_Reference_System_1993",
SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["False_Easting",200000.0],
PARAMETER["False_Northing",-3500000.0],
PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",33.0],
PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.99995],
PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],
UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

These have to get an official acknowledgment to be put into the EPSG database. Until then, you have to use a custom CRS if you are working outside of the ESRI world.

The equivalent Proj.4 string is

`+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=33 +k=0.99995 +x_0=200000 +y_0=-3500000 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs`

---

**UPDATE**

The CRS is no in the EPSG database as [EPSG:6312](https://epsg.io/6312)

Comment: I tried to use a SHP file in  Qgis and could not find the coordinate system of Cyprus.

Comment: If the shapefile has a .prj file, QGIS should create a custom CRS automatically from it.