# Getting EPSG from Feature Classes of Geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase, epsg

Where can I find the EPSG code of a Feature Class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browse your feature class in `ArcCatalog -> Properties -> XY Coordinate System`, as you can see below:

[image]

OR:

When you load the feature class into the table of content (TOC), right-click the in the view and go to `Data Frame Properties -> Coordinate System` and you will find it there. Or you can go to the `Layers (in the TOC)-> Properties -> Coordinate System`  as you can see below:

[image]

Comment: That is where I was looking. However, I found the code 102329 there, which google doesn't seem to know. I beleave it should be EPSG 4647.And why is it WKID and not EPSG? Is it always the same?

Comment: I think this link will answer your question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/18675/63384, so in your case they are not the same, and the ID you have is ESRI defined WKID.

Comment: If they are looking at the Table of Contents then they will be in ArcMap and I think probably better to use its Catalog window rather than ArcCatalog for which there have been few use cases since 10.0 was released.

Comment: @ ahmadhanb Yes, that answers my question. And thanks to all for answers and comments.

Comment: (Esri employee here) We added a set of zones marked 7 stellen and 8 stellen upon customer request which included 102329. We haven't linked it to a particular EPSG code. EPSG::4647 was linked to our existing 102362. This is partially complicated by the axis ordering. If a ProjCRS has northing-easting ordering Esri needs to handle it differently than if it's easting-northing (our default).

Comment: As of 2019, still a problem: stuff like this is causing major headaches for practicioners who only get the info "this data is/this data must be delivered in ETRS89 Zone 32 N".  You might set all your layers to one CRS and only later realise that some of them were delivered in a different flavor of ETRS89 Zone 32N, e.g. EPSG 25832, EPSG 102329 and EPSG 4647. 

Advice: be kind and tell your customers and contractors to include the EPSG information, found as shown above.