# Adding spatial reference to many shapefiles in loop using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, error-999999

`AST` folder has 5 shapefiles.
This code tries to pass the `2100` coordinate system to these shapefiles. But it gives error 999999:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\roads\AST" 
for i in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
     sr = arcpy.SpatialReference("EPSG:2100")
     arcpy.DefineProjection_management(i, sr)
```

How to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference("EPSG:2100")
```

try:

```
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(2100)
```

[Do ArcGIS SpatialReference object factory codes correspond with EPSG numbers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18651) is worth reviewing for information about using EPSG codes in ArcMap.